# Converting tuples in tuple to lists in list

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, tuples

I am at the last step of my code where I am supposed to change my preferred laptops back to a list which are already in a descending order.

The tuples in the tuple list represent `(ranking score, (name, company, screen size))`.

For example:

```
tuple_lst = [(20,('Elitebook','HP',13)),(10,('SurfacePro','Microsoft',13)),(5,('MacBook Air','Apple',13))]
```

My expected output:

```
[['Elitebook','HP',13],['SurfacePro','Microsoft',13],['MacBook Air','Apple',13]]
```

I have tried using `list()` and creating `for` loops but still failed to do so.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below using list comprehension :

```
tuple_lst = [(20,('Elitebook','HP',13)),(10,('SurfacePro','Microsoft',13)),(5,('MacBook Air','Apple',13))]

print([list(x[1]) for x in tuple_lst])
```

Answer (score 2):

you do something like that

```
new_lst = [list(i[1]) for i in tuple_lst]
```

output

```
[['Elitebook', 'HP', 13],
 ['SurfacePro', 'Microsoft', 13],
 ['MacBook Air', 'Apple', 13]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tuple_lst = [(20,('Elitebook','HP',13)),(10,('SurfacePro','Microsoft',13)),(5,('MacBook Air','Apple',13))]
res = []

for tup in tuple_lst:
    res.append(list(tup[1]))

print(res)
```

Output will be:-

```
[['Elitebook','HP',13],['SurfacePro','Microsoft',13],['MacBook Air','Apple',13]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice way is to use tuple unpacking:

```
>>> tuple_lst = [(20,('Elitebook','HP',13)),(10,('SurfacePro','Microsoft',13)),(5,('MacBook Air','Apple',13))]
>>> [list(y) for _, y in tuple_lst]
[['Elitebook', 'HP', 13], ['SurfacePro', 'Microsoft', 13], ['MacBook Air', 'Apple', 13]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one line solution for your problem:

```
    tuple_lst = [(20,('Elitebook','HP',13)),(10,('SurfacePro','Microsoft',13)),(5,('MacBook Air','Apple',13))]
    tuple_lst = list(map(lambda x:list(x[1]),tuple_lst))
    print(tuple_lst)
```

Output:
[['Elitebook', 'HP', 13], ['SurfacePro', 'Microsoft', 13], ['MacBook Air', 'Apple', 13]]